# Check if both items in a list meet certain criteria

Tags: python, list

Question re-write:

I am making a game where 2 players have 2 pieces each. They win the game if both their pieces are on space `11`. The scoring is set up like this:

```
player_one = [1, 1]  
player_two = [1, 1]
player_scores = [player_one, player_two]
```

Is there a way to check if their scores look like this:

```
player_one = [11,11]
```

Comment: Where is this "space 11"? The list only has two values.

Comment: what about `player_one == [1,1] and player_one == player_two` ?

Comment: @aaron I edited your question. If I inadvertently changed the meaning of the question, please edit the question and clarify what the question's intended meaning is.

Comment: @Khaelid you should not adapt the question to the answers. If the OP doesn't clarify himself, this question should rather be closed as _unclear what you're asking_.

Comment: @moooeeeep I agree. I re-read the question after posting my edit, and then realized it was unclear. But my edit had already been peer approved, so I couldn't fix it. So I explained myself in the comment.

Comment: @moooeeep  - re-written question. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to check if both players are `[1, 1]` you could do it like this, using the builtin [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function

```
player_one = [1, 1]  
player_two = [1, 1]
player_scores = [player_one, player_two]

if all(x == [1, 1] for x in player_scores):
    print 'Both are on [1, 1]'
```

This works for more players too, if you were to add a `player_three` to `player_scores` it would check that as well

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution which comes to my mind:

```
def are_all_values_equal(the_list):
    return len(set(the_list))==1
```

Right, I missunderstood.

```
def are_all_values_equal_to(the_list, value):
    s = set(the_list)
    if len(s) != 1:
        return False

    return s.pop() == value
```

Comment: Oh, right, I assumed "all elements in list are equal". My bad.

Comment: I didn't downvote; I just think that the OP hasn't clarified his question enough for us to be able to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a list as short as that, you could simply do this with two nested for loops

```
def both_on_eleven(scores):
    for score in scores:
        for individual_score in score:
            if individual_score != 1:
                return False
     return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two player scores and you want to test if both have an equal value of `[11, 11]` it seems straightforward to translate this to a simple boolean expression:

```
players_score_check = player_one == [11, 11] and player_one == player_two
```

Of course you can also build a list of the player scores and use the built-in `all()` function to check each score iteratively, like another answer suggests, but I think this would be overkill in this situation.

For reference:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all